# backend doesn't found for apple auth

Tags: python, django, oauth

I use `django auth` system with this [document](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

I set each `BACKENDS` in `settins.py`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.apple.AppleIdAuth',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
)
```

then try to use `url` in `template`.

```
    <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">Google login</a>
    <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'apple' %}">Apple login</a>
    <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}">Facebook login</a>
```

`google` and `facebook` works correctly, but for `apple`

shows `404 error`

```
Page not found (404)
Backend not found
```

How can I find the template name for apple??

Comment: provider name is apple-id as far as I can see
https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/social_core/backends/apple.py

Comment: Thank you , it works. You gave me the nice link, i can check the name in source code.

Comment: Hi, did you get the error: Session value state missing? I have that problem with setting apple